# Background not animating when using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, transition

I am using css-transitions which are added using jquery for a slideshow though for some reason it is not animating the background of the element.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-webkit-transition-property', 'background');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-webkit-transition-timing-function', 'linear');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-webkit-transition-duration', du);
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-moz-transition-property', 'background');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-moz-transition-timing-function', 'linear');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-moz-transition-duration', du);
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-o-transition-property', 'background');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-o-transition-timing-function', 'linear');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-o-transition-duration', du);
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-ms-transition-property', 'background');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-ms-transition-timing-function', 'linear');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('-ms-transition-duration', du);
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('transition-property', 'background');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('transition-timing-function', 'linear');
$(this).find('.pagers').children().css('transition-duration', du);
```

I can't just use a regular css transition because I am using a variable.

I have already tried to do .animate instead though it didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/uf5gE/

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does _"I can't just use a regular one because I am using a variable."_ mean? A regular what and what kind of variable?

Comment: I can't use css as this is a plugin where you set a duration for the slideshow

Comment: the variable is set by the user of the plugin

Comment: Ah, a variable for the duration.

Comment: The css() method accepts an object so you don't have to write everything multiple times. Otherwise, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way the variable is used, so either your selector is wrong, your variable isn't what you think it is, or your not setting the appropriate css properties. There's no way for us to know unless you set up a fiddle or something we can actually test ?

Comment: see this try to write your css this way : http://jsfiddle.net/QzaSu/ it helps finding problem...

Comment: nope already tried and failed

Comment: Don't think jQuery supports all CSS3 transitions.., try using **[this](https://gist.github.com/jonraasch/373874)** for better support.

Comment: I would prefer to use no extra code from other sources

Comment: I works exactly as intended? When inspecting the element the styles do change, but the set styles don't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sth like this:

```
$('.pager').css({
      '-webkit-transition' : 'background-color '+du+'s linear'      
});
```

of course you have to add code for all browsers